# Android: View multiple image with system image viewer

Tags: android, image, view, android-intent

We can view an image with code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();  
intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);  
File file = new File("/sdcard/test.jpg");  
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "image/*");  
startActivity(intent);
```

What if we have some images? How can we put the extras to let the viewer know we have

/sdcard/a.jpg, /sdcard/b.jpg, /sdcard/c.jpg ?

I hope to do this in a time because starting an activity is very expensive.

can any one help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can't.

The whole system of intents and uris is to either do an action on one item, or do an action on all items. See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html and search for "content://contacts/people/1" and "content://contacts/people/" Have you tried looking for the intent that would let the viewer show all images in "/sdcard/". Even better is to plug into the content provider of that native viewer.